# Вот что не так? вычисляем площадь треугольника

Tags: java

Вот что не так? Вычисляем площадь.

```
public class Challenge
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        double a;

    a = triangleArea(3, 3, 3);
    System.out.println("A triangle with sides 3,3,3 has an area of:" + a);

    a = triangleArea(3, 4, 5);
    System.out.println("A triangle with sides 3,4,5 has an area of:" + a);

    a = triangleArea(9, 9, 9);
    System.out.println("A triangle with sides 9,9,9 has an area of:" + a );

    }

    public static double triangleArea( int a, int b, int c )
    {
    double s=(((a+b+c)/2)*((a+b+c)/2-a)*((a+b+c)/2-b)*((a+b+c)/2-c));
    return Math.sqrt(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: и что не так? где не так? не компилится, неправильно вычисляет, что ? что не устраивает?

Comment: int замените на double. у вас 9/2==4

Comment: @Исмаил Исмаилов, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делите всюду на `2.0`, а не на 2 и все заработает (думаю, сами сообразите почему).

Подсказка -- почитайте об арифметике в целых и приведении типов (преобразованиях числовых типов) по умолчанию.

--

И понятней было бы написать:

```
 double pp = (a + b + c) / 2.0;  // полупериметр
 return Math.sqrt(pp * (pp - a) * (pp - b) * (pp - c)); // прямо по формуле Герона из вики
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Изначальное int в задании ввело меня в обман.